# Saving a web url to filepicker.io

Tags: filepicker.io

Given some image url, is there a simple way to upload this to filepicker? I want to do this for two reasons:

1. So that I'm not consuming the image hoster's bandwidth/bugging them
2. So that I can easily resize the image

I feel like this could be done with a read and then store call to filepicker; is this the way I should do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

storeUrl, of course!

I missed this because it's under the "store" section, and there's not a "storeUrl" section. I also expected store to just take a url, I'm not sure why these are two separate methods, but I presume there's some good reason.

Comment: Glad you found it! This was a long debate internally, but because you can say filepicker.store("Hello World"), we can't reliably determine if you give us a string whether we should store that string or treat it as a URL and go grab it and store the contents. Sorry for the confusion!